# Working with a cloud app and local private database

Tags: java, performance, cloud, crm, erp

We are developing a cloud ERP product using java and want to provide the users to have an option to work either with a local database file or the database on the cloud. To some of our customers, their data is very sensitive and they do not want their data stored on web server, instead want to have the database on their own server/pc.

Will this kind of offering be technically viable, secure & effective to implement and maintain? If so, can anyone recommend the best work around for this kind of architecture where the application on our cloud server can work seamlessly with the local database?

Many Thanks

LJ

Comment: Customer could expose a database via authenticated restful interface over https.  Cloud app connects to that.  Mongo and Neo could be used for this.

Answer (score 1):

For your customers concerned with security, maybe using a local datastore such as MySQL running on a local server and a local instance of the ERP product, also running on a local server.   And I would advise encrypting all sensitive columns using something like AES_ENCRYPT() -- even on this local database.

Otherwise I don't know of a way to run a hosted App with a secured local database without introducing all kinds of data vulnerabilities.